# How can I get stitched images of same size for all frames from one video?

Tags: video-processing, opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching, python

I am trying to stitch two video clips into one using Opencv Stitcher class.
It works well for each image but the problem is that the stitched images have different sizes slightly.
So, I can't combine them into a result video. How can I solve this problem?
Am I missing something in the process of video stitching?
I am using opencv 4.5 and moviepy to combine the frames into video clip.

Comment: why can't you combine them? you are stitching them, right? perhaps show some pictures/video to illustrate

Comment: Because each frame has different sizes. To combine them, they should be a sam size of the frame like 1980*1080. In my case, after stitching each frame using the Stitcher class, their sizes are varying slightly.

Comment: ah, so for every set of frames, you need to place the composite in a fixed size frame. do your cameras move, or are they fixed?

Comment: It is fixed. I want to know which process causing this problem inside of Stitcher class. Now I am looking through the 'stitching_detailed.py' to understand the stitching pipeline

Comment: estimate the transform for your cameras once, then reuse it. that should give you the same resolution for every set of frames.